# Java read line from console longer than 1024 characters

Tags: java, io, console

I have the following code, first branch is for file reading (works perfectly for file lines of any size), but is I try the same for console input, the reading blocks after 1024 characters. As there is no difference besides the source stream, I suppose that there is some limitation in System.in.

Can you please point me to some property where can I change (?internal buffer size?) of System.in.

Thanks!

```
        if (input != null) {
            reader = new MyReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(input))));
        } else {
            reader = new MyReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        }
```

Comment: My guess would be some limitation in the implementation of your console...

Comment: Does this also happen when standard input is redirected from a file?

Comment: What OS is the command line console?

Comment: MacOS, I tried ITerm and the embedded console. Problem is the same in both...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can do it like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int ch = 0;
while((ch = System.in.read()) != '\n') {
    sb.append((char)ch);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: `System.in` is buffered by default this code will not do anything useful.